# Can "on VERBing" be ambiguous?

Tags: prepositions, expressions, gerunds, ambiguity

**[SOURCE](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/on_1?q=on)**

Oxford Learner's dictionary says, in its definition of ***on***:

> **5** immediately after something
>   ***On arriving*** home I discovered they had gone.
>   *There was a letter waiting for him **on his return.***

But I think it's more like 'when' than 'after', isn't it?

What does, for example, *"On returning from holidays"* mean? After arriving home? Can't this also mean "On the way home" and even "When about to get going home"?

Comment: I think, in this case, "on" is being used as if it were "upon".

Comment: *It rained (up)on our arrival.*  Was it already raining when we arrived, or did it start raining soon after we arrived?

Comment: A native speaker from UK was saying "On returning from Rome, he wrote to the ~ (This indicates that he wrote whilst he was in Rome)" https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/preposition-in-participle-clauses.3342454/#post-16935110.

Comment: _"Immediately **when** something"_ is not meaningful in English. The adverbial is not just _after_, but _immediately after_, and it could arguably be _at the moment of_. The definition is not a monument to clarity, certainly, but dictionaries are notoriously bad references for prepositions, and _on_, as a part of many phrasal verbs, has a dizzying number of usages. (_"When about to get going home"_ is very poorly constructed, but it can't substitute for _on arriving home,_ which means _"At the moment of arriving home"_.)

Comment: _"On returning from Rome, he wrote to the Italian embassy"_ means _"After he returned from Rome, he wrote to the Italian embassy."_ He was no longer in Rome. There is not really ambiguity, but imprecision in _on returning_. The period described by _on returning_ begins with the moment of his return, but has no fixed duration. It means _"pretty soon after he got back"_ in the American idiom.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo *On* seems to me to entail a **point** in time or space, not a timespan: *on our arrival* therefore means the moment at which we arrived. This does not preclude our arriving at a moment located within a timespan during which it rained. Since *rain* is an activity verb *it rained* will sustain either an imperfective or an inceptive sense. BUT:I don't think most of us would actually use *rained* here: they'd disambiguate with either *it was raining* or *it started raining*.

Comment: @StoneyB:  I would paraphrase **on arriving** as "when I got there" and  **having arrived** as "now that I was there". Is that how you understand them?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Pretty much, yeah.

Comment: If you'd like to answer your own question, please **post an answer**.  Please do not edit your question itself to contain what you believe is the answer.  If you've already posted an answer, please feel free to **edit** that answer to include any new information you've found which supports it.

Comment: Why do you have to do that? Editing the most visible part would save the time of the visitors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found an example.

> "***On opening the box, be prepared for a slight surprise***, as the kit has been (...)."

"(***up***)***on handling***" or "(***up***)***on delivery***" mean "*when handling*" and "*when delivering*," and therefore they are ambiguous, needing context to be clear.

"On arriving home, I noticed a new store had been opened nearby" means just before you arrived home. You can say this before actually enter your house. This is not because 'home' means hometown, but because 'on' doesn't have any sense of 'after.'

So, this statement

> "On returning from Rome, he wrote to the ~ (This indicates that *he wrote whilst he was in Rome*)"

is indeed correct. It can mean he wrote when he was ***about to leave Rome***. 
I do trust this writer's sense of language as much above average.

> **on the occasion of**
>   (formal) at the time of an important event
>   *on the occasion of his second wedding*
>   from [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/on-the-occasion-of-something)
>
> Synonyms: at the time when, (...)
>   from [WordReference English Thesaurus](http://www.wordreference.com/synonyms/on%20the%20occasion%20of)

More: ***[on](http://www.wordreference.com/synonyms/on)***
'***On***' has the sense of 'upon,' 'toward,' 'forward,' 'near,' but **not** '**after**.'

Comment: I don't agree that "on" can mean "just before". It either means at the same time, or shortly afterwards. "On arriving home, I noticed that..." would mean that you were on the doorstep when you noticed that the new store. "On returning from Rome, he wrote..." would mean that he wrote very soon after arriving at home.

Comment: And I do not agree with you. :)

Answer (score 1):

*On [some event]* is frequently used to add an element of *drama* to a sentence, to imply that one event happened after another with no time for preparation or thought.  As Catija's comment says, "on arriving home" can mean the same as "*upon* arriving home", which is to say, "*at the moment* of arrival".  Example:

> **On seeing the roach** she grabbed the can of bug spray.

As P.E. Dant's comment points out, it can also be an imprecise statement that means *soon after* some event, where the exact amount of time is not important:

> **On their return** they found waiting for them a mysterious package addressed simply, 'To the residents of this house'.